How can we read program counter through assembly code in 68k microcontroller
Can anybody please explain how program counter can be read using assembly instruction in MC68000 controller.
Following instruction set gave error -  undefined addressing mode
MOVE.L %PC, %D0
Also tried following assembly code but got error
MOVEA %PC, %D0
MOVE.L %PC,(0x4ffff0).L

Try an lea instruction.

But i want to read Program counter content and lea will modify the content of program counter register

Any instruction will advance the program counter, so you can accommodate by using an offset of -4 or so.  In that sense, lea no different from mov.

Can you please explain through assembly code example

Try something like lea -4(pc),a0 — and adjust the offset to get the result you want.  Alternatively, the bsr/jsr instructions will push a return address onto the stack, which you can pop off to get a pc value.  The pea instruction does similar without the branching part.

Can you please explain example of getting pc value through bsr /jsr instruction or pea instruction using assembly code

What's your real question?  Why do you want to read the program counter value more-or-less directly, as you must realize that by definition, the PC is constantly changing during execution of instruction after instruction in a program or instruction stream?  (The program counter value is automatically read, in an orderly fashion, in order to perform procedure/subroutine/function calling and subsequent returning to caller), but there's little to no need to look at a return value.  Otherwise, if you're using the program counter as the base for an addressing mode, the assembler can help with that.

PC is not a general purpose register in 68000 assembly, and thus limited in its accessibility.
You can form effective addresses relative to the PC and you can indirectly affect the PC by branches, jumps, the RTS and some other instructions, but you cannot access (or use) that register directly. In particular, MOVE and PEA to and from the PC are not part of the instruction set.
    lea 0(pc),a0

will (if your assembler accepts it, most assemblers will consider literal PC offsets an error, because they are not a commonly used - or useful, for real programs - construct) load a0 with the current (whatever you might consider current value of the PC). Current here means the extension word of the above instruction.
An alternative way to access the PC is through subroutine calls and stack examination like in
      bsr.s subrout
      nop
   subrout:
      move.l (sp)+,a0

this will put the address of the NOP instruction into a0 (obviously, that will always be a past and not the current PC value).

Getting your own address is potentially useful for a position-independent code fragment (like shellcode that can be injected into something and run from any address).  e.g. to reference static data that's part of the same byte sequence, or to make self-modifying code.

@PeterCordes I tend to disagree: The absolute value of your own address  (i.e., PC) is relatively irrelevant to any piece of code. With PC-relative addressing modes, the 68k is able to adress bytes relative to PC, for example constant data within its program segments (or, god beware, code that it wants to self-modify...)  - which is interesting - but the value of PC is not. The M68k works with PC-relative addressing modes, but hides the PC value from the programming model.

... and the above two code examples might be good examples of how irrelevant the absolute value of PC is  (for "normal" applications, except for maybe debuggers and other code inspection tools) - The first example gives you an address  that points in the middle (second word) of an instruction, while stack examination gives you an address that points to the first word of an instruction. You really want an assembler to support you for the first case.

Instead of lea 0(pc),a0 I would always use a label like before: lea before(pc),a0 (or use a label after the instruction), so I know for sure what the address points to. Still OP may want to clarify when/why they actually need this.

@chtz Of Course you would always use a label, predominantly because most 68k assemblers force you to and sensible assembly programs don't have registers pointing somewhere in the middle of an instruction like here. But if you want the momentary PC current while the instruction is executed (and not somewhere before or after), which seems to be the point of this question, you'll have to use a constant 0 (or a label set to constant 0). I think I pointed this out in the answer when referring to the fact that literal offsets are normally useless.

Oh right, you can just use PC-relative addressing modes for both the use-cases I mentioned, potentially with labels.
